# C# Unity Engine, how to limit UI Slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need to limit UI Slider.

Now i want the Slider to Stop, if the Limit is 0, but being able to slide back and decrease their value.

like:

```
Min = 0;
Max = 20;
Limit = Max-SliderValues;

SliderValues = Slider1.value+Slider2.value+Slider3.value+slider4.value;
Slider1.value = 10;
Slider2.value = 2;
Slider3.value = 2;
Slider4.value = max 6;
```

Can this be done with Unity?

Example:

One slider can reach max and if so, no slider can be moved until the maxed slider has been decreased. I'll give an example:

```
Workers in Sum: 100;
Assigned workers: Mining+Fishing+Crafting+Gym;
Workers available : 100-Assigned workers;
```

You have 4 Sliders: Mining, Fishing, Crafting, Gym

Each slider decreases Worker Available and increases Assigned Workers.
The theoretical maximum is 100, practical Workers available.
The Sliders need to stop when WA = 0, but the Problem is, with the decreasing Value, the Slider stops at half and all Sliders will jump back to 0 if you try to push them further as the value allows.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just use: 
**Slider1.minValue = desiredMinValue;**
or
**Slider1.maxValue = desiredMaxValue;**

Here's the documentation for UI sliders if you have anymore issues with them: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html

Comment: @Ghost2k20 Constantly read each slider's values and change each *.maxValue* up or down during runtime.

Comment: The problem has been solved, but i don't know if i'm allow to shared here.